# Increasing ajax button rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm having trouble for this button:

controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

def test

@product = Product.find(params[:my][:id])
@k = params[:my][:k]
@product.update_attribute :amount, @product.amount + @k.to_i
respond_to do |format|
  format.js 
  format.html
end
end
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:amount)
end
```

view:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<td class="ajax">
        <%= product.amount %>
</td>
<td><%= link_to '+1', {controller: 'products', action: 'test', 
            my: {id: product.id, k: '1'}}, 
            :method => :post, :remote => true, 
            class: "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
</td>
```

test.js.erb:

```
$(".ajax").html("<%= @product.amount %>")
```

routes:

```
resources :products
post 'products/test'
```

when I press the button, every product is updated with the value of product corrisponding to the button, refreshing the page every value is correct. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet all of your products have css class `ajax`. Try to use id instead.

**Edit:**

Your view:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <td id="product-<%= product.id %>">
    <%= product.amount %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to '+1', {controller: 'products', action: 'test', 
              my: {id: product.id, k: '1'}}, 
              :method => :post, :remote => true, 
              class: "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

test.js.erb:

`$("#product-<%= @product.id %>").html("<%= @product.amount %>")`

Comment: I have only one button for now... How can I use id? I'm very confusing :)

Comment: I try this: <td id="ppp"> <%= product.amount %> </td> in the view and $(".ppp").html("<%= @product.amount %>") in the js.erb, now works fine on the db, but it's not updating dinamically, I have to refresh the page to see changed value...

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong with buttons. I mean each your product has `ajax` class. And `$(".ajax")` selector selects all elements with this class. `id` attribute should be unique for all elements. No two elements can have the same ID value in a single document. That's why you should use selector by id. To select element by id use `#` like `$('#element-id-here')`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Answer accepted! Sorry for delay, I am not very familiar with stack... I  received this question based on your solution, maybe (if you want) you can help him... [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174130/rails-database-operations-performed-twice)  (I don't have any ideas...) Thanks again for your help!!!