# rails database operations performed twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have followed the answer of BearGrylls on this question: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705660/solved-increasing-ajax-button-rails)

It works fine on heroku, but on localhost it increase by two on every product in index view. Does it depend by an errate configuration of my Rails 4.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 (ruby 2.2.0p0) or I missed something?

Comment: have a look into log/developent.log to find out. i think you can benefit from reading this blog post on debugging your application http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
bundle exec rake assets:clean
```

clean your browser's cache

Comment: It works! Thanks! I spent days to find a solution to this problem!